# Can someone tell me basic difference b/w MQL4 and MT4?

Tags: metatrader4, mql4

Please illustrate the difference with code.I am new in it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

MT4- Meta Trader is the application, MQL is the programming language in MT4.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>MT4</kbd>  is an abbreviation of a MetaTrader software. It has a Server part -- a MetaTrader Server suite, which is licensed from MetaQuotes, Inc., for being run at the Broker-side, and there are also MetaTrader terminals, the Client-side, programmes, that are typically "White-Labeled/branded" by the respective broker company, so as to be allowed to be used by their investors / customers. These two parts together ( Client/Server ) setup an investor's access to the FOREX market.

<kbd>MQL4</kbd> stands for MetaQuotes Language 4, which is a programming language, that a MetaTrader Terminal can understand and can become automated / controlled by several different types of software. These principal types are called <kbd>MQL4-Expert Advisor</kbd> for automated trading functions, <kbd>MQL4-Custom Indicator</kbd> for non-trading calculations alike computation and presentation of graphical output of Technical Analysis indicator lines, <kbd>MQL4-Script</kbd> for one-stop calculations being executed independently of the previous two principal types of mql4-code(s)